# CSS behavior difference between development version and published version in IE10

Tags: css, asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-10

We have created an ASP.NET website, and so far the little CSS we have used has worked fine. We tested in on the VM's in IE 10.0.9200.16899. Now we have published the website on our development server in IIS 7 for testing purposes, and when I open up the site on the VM (opening the same browser), there are layout differences; some severe, some not quite so.

To give examples: (1) We are using Infragistics components, and their styling seems to be very near to the original for the most part (some differences in font size, symbol size, ..., but very small).

(2) The following hover transition in the bootstrap navbar works on the site that starts up from within Visual Studio, but not with the deployed version on the development server. The colors are correct, though, and the hover color changes as well; it's the transition that's missing in the deployed version.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #3b3b3b;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ff9900;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

(3) I styled a button to have a gradient background and an image (icon) on the left on top of the background gradient, as well as one rounded corner. But in the deployed version, the whole button is grayed out, the image is missing, and I can't make out a rounded corner. The rest of the CSS works fine, though, as far as I can see.

```
.MyButton {
  background: url("/img/SomeIcon.png") no-repeat 8px center, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #374a9a 0%, #061671 70%);
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  /* Some other font stuff and padding that still works fine */
}
```

It's my first time publishing a website, and so far I always thought that style differences were mostly related to differences in browser brands and versions. But this problem has to be something else, maybe IIS-related? Any suggestions or ideas as to why this could differ so much are greatly appreciated. Somehow (2) and (3) seem vaguely related, since both the gradient and the transition animation are something that I'd naively think of as "needing some sort of rendering".

Could a difference between IIS versions be the reason? Visual Studio seems to host the application in an IIS Express (How can I find out the version? I see IIS Express 8.0 installed, but the property in my project just says "IIS Express"), while the server hosting the site has IIS 7.0 installed. Any input or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have compatibility view on either of them, or are you using the developer tools to render them as earlier versions / quirks mode on either?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin You seem to be on to something there. When I click on the compatibility mode icon in the development version (so that it's now blue; that means ON I guess?), the site behaves in the same - wrong - way. But when I open the deployed version, there is no compatibility icon :-/ I'll try finding out how to set (or not set, rather) the compatibility mode in HTML.

Comment: Have a look in the IE developer tools (F12), there's probably a setting in there that's off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have one of the browsers in either compatabiity mode, or are using the F12 developer tools to render it as an older version of IE/quirks mode.

Comment: There are no two browsers, though, that's what bothers me. It's the same browser. I can even open up the page from within VS (F5), then open up a new tab in the then open IE10 to show the deployed page, and they differ. Strangely, turning *on* compatibility mode on the development page makes it as bad as the deployed version, but there I can't turn it *off*. I'll try changing a page setting to never use compatibility mode, if that's possible, and then accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to programmatically disable compatibility mode for the site? Or at least let it be *off* by default? Since the Developer Tools show that compatibility view for IE10 is enabled, but I haven't set this anywhere, and the clients who will be using the site don't have the possibility to turn this setting on/off at all.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe there's an error in your code somewhere then. I don't think there's a way of problematically disabling it, *but* it will switch on by default if there's a big error in the code.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it correctly points out why that's happening. It's not a code error though; I found out that the IE option is checked which shows every **intranet** site in compatibility mode. I can't seem to "fix" this :/ I can set "IE=edge", but it screws up my design in another way and the compatibility is still on. I hope I can find another way around this, but it seems unlikely. Disabling the option is something an admin would have to do globally, and won't do for sure because there's many old applications running in the intranet.

Comment: Yes! I came up across this myself a year back.