# Is disabling browser compatibility mode for intranet sites programmatically possible?

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524781/css-behavior-difference-between-development-version-and-published-version-in-ie1/24525673?noredirect=1#comment37980969_24525673) I encountered a style difference between the development version of our website and the deployed one. It turned out to be the compatibility mode issue that hundreds of people here have posted about.

However, most of the proposed solutions just change the document mode, not the browser mode (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)). The company we're doing the site for has forced the setting "Show intranet sites in compatibility mode" on everyone, so even if I use the `IE=edge` approach - in either a `meta` tag or via `<customHeaders>` - the site is displayed in compatibility mode. Now we're using some sophisticated components and other CSS styling that are displayed falsely, crudely, or not at all in compatibility mode, but perfectly if it's off.

Is there **any** way around this compatibility mode behavior? Since I'm pretty sure an administrator wouldn't want to get rid of this setting.

If this is not possible: Do you have any proposal as to what I can do then? It seems to be hard to style and program towards compatibility mode. Since some controls and fonts have different sizes, some borders have different colours, than the ones specified in the CSS, among other stuff like transitions and gradients not working at all. Like, we are supposed to have our buttons styled so that there are particular rounded corners, and they don't work either....

Comment: Give the site an IP that makes it look like it's not an intranet site.

Comment: I had the same problem a few days ago and a meta tag solved it... Did you try this one? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

Comment: @NicolasHenrard Yes I did; as I wrote above, neither the meta tag nor the custom header approach worked, since they change (as far as I understood) only the document mode, but not the browser mode.

Comment: @Ariel That sounds interesting, though I'm not sure it's possible here (we're kind of confined in every possible way^^). How would I go about this?

Comment: Weird. I read it but I don't understand how the problem still exist. Be sure to clean browser cache, it may cause problems.

Comment: @NicolasHenrard Quite some people seem to have this issue. In the comments under the highest voted answer in the linked question there also some upvotes for a comment which states the above :/ It's not like `IE=10` or `IE=edge` has no effect, but rather that it screws up the layout even more in combination with the compatibility mode that's still on (in the developer tools I can see it and disable it, but only on my VM, and then the site is perfect).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Oh, you're right, I must have missed that one! I guess not much has changed there since IE8, sadly :/